# Excel VBA userform works fine in development page but wont work right from macro key

Tags: vba, excel, formatting

This is an odd one that I have never seen before. So my code works when I run it in the environment but when I run it from the macro I assigned it to within the excel spreadsheet, the ID number is crazy high. This is the code:

```
Dim AN As Worksheet
Set AN = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("A.N. Data")
Dim n As Long
Dim LstRw As Long

'tells system where the next empty line is at so it doesn't overwrite data
n = AN.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'tells system the value of the last cell in 'row a'
LstRw = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Auto increments ID or 'row a' by one
AN.Range("A" & n + 1).Value = Cells(LstRw, "A").Value + 1
```

The last line in the code snippet is what affects the ID number. Now when I run it through the VBA environment, it works just like it should. I set up a macro key on the database to easily access it from the excel spreadsheet. The macro key opens it up no problem and puts all information in excel correctly except for the ID number. So instead of it being 8473, it becomes 43267. Any ideas what it may be?

Comment: A good start would be to make sure all of your Range/Cells calls are qualified with a worksheet reference.

Comment: Looks like they are. I am assuming by that you meant make sure they are referencing something in the worksheet. if not then just let me know

Comment: `Cells(LstRw, "A").Value + 1` will refer to whatever worksheet happens to be active when it runs.  That can lead to unexpected behavior.  Likewise `LstRw = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out! For some reason I do not know, Just doing AN.Range("A" & n + 1).Value = n + 0 Didn't seem to work, but when I made LstRw = 0 and did " AN.Range("A" & n + 1).Value = n + LstRw " instead, it worked!